# How to add Samsung Galaxy backup to a Xiaomi (different Android) phone?

Tags: samsung, backup, restore, xiaomi, samsung-smart-switch

I had a Samsung Galaxy A8 (2018) phone but its display was dying, so I managed to get a backup of the phone through the Samsung Switch app to my laptop.

Now I got a new Xiaomi phone and I want to add the backup to it, how can I do that?

Comment: Related: [How can I restore a backup made using Samsung Switch onto an LG phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/238549/44325)

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

The Samsung Switch software allows taking a backup *from* most non-Samsung phones including iPhone and old Windows phones and, of course, other Android phones, but can only recover backups *to* Samsung Galaxy phones.

> Note: Smart Switch lets you transfer content from old phones to Galaxy devices only. For example, you cannot transfer content to an iOS device.

Source: https://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00062998/